# Use javascript to replace broken image of a particular tag in Ruby On Rails views

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I want to show the avatar of a user in a view, but the image is sometimes missing, hence the `missing.png` is showed instead. How do I replace it with a default image? 
(Note: I don't want to replace all broken images in the view with it, just the one I'm interested in).

I've done some googling and found this javascript function, but not sure how to use it in my view (`.html.havl` file) (I'm VERY new to Ruby on Rails)

```
$('img').error(function(){
 $(this).attr('src', '<<<REPLACE URL>>>');
});
```

Here's my view

```
...
.user_avatar
 %img{:src => @user.avatar.url} <<<< how do I make the 'src' points to the default image 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a more specific selector on the JS side:

```
$(".user_avatar img").on('error', function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'replace-url');
});
```

If you want to do this on the RoR side, you can check that `@user.avatar.url` exists if it's on the same filesystem or even using an HTTP request.

Comment: So just put this block of code at the beginning of the view file? (As I said, I''m new to Ruby On Rails, sorry about the simplicity of the question!)

Comment: And by the way, I put it at the top (after prepending `:javascript` to the block, the `missing.png` is still showing in place of my default image. Do I have to call the function or something?

Comment: About your comment on the RoR side, I do this in my helper method `if defined? user.avatar.url`.

Comment: @OneTwoThree I think that that only works if the variable itself is defined, not if the file exists.

Comment: Ok, well, about the javascript... It doesn't seem to work for my case. It seemed that when the image doesn't exist, `misisng.png` is used automatically without raising any error (which is why the javascript function didn't get called)?